# $\mbox{tr}((AB)^2) = \mbox{tr} (A^2B^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

> Let $\mathbb K$ be a field with characteristic $3$ and $A, B \in M_3(\mathbb K)$ such that $\mbox{tr}((AB)^2) = \mbox{tr} (A^2B^2)$.
>
> 1. Show that $(AB-BA)^3$ is a scalar matrix.
> 2. Find a couple solution $(A,B) \in M_3 (\mathbb F_3)$ such that $AB-BA$ is not a scalar matrix.

Attemp: I tried to develop the cube and that of properties of trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that (using the properties of trace), 
$$
\operatorname{tr}[(AB - BA)^2] = 
\operatorname{tr}(ABAB - ABBA - BAAB + BABA)
\\ = 2\operatorname{tr}((AB)^2) - 2\operatorname{tr}(A^2B^2).
$$
So, the $M = AB - BA$ satisfies $\operatorname{tr}(M) = 0$ and $\operatorname{tr}(M^2) = 0$. Now, the [characteristic polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html) of $M$ is given by
$$
\det(M - tI) = -t^3 + \operatorname{tr}(M)t^2 - \frac 12 [\operatorname{tr}^2(M) - \operatorname{tr}(M^2)] t+ \det(M) \\= -t^3 + \det(M).
$$
By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, it follows that 
$$
0 = -M^3 + \det(M) I \implies M^3 = \det(M) I.
$$
So indeed, $M^3$ is a scalar matrix.

---

For part 2, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}, \quad
B = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0}.
$$

Comment: It seems to me that you got the first equation by assuming $\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)=\operatorname{tr}((AB-BA)^2)$, but I fail to see why it's true - can you please explain?

Comment: @Asaf I was missing an exponent, see my latest edit

Comment: Thanks. but now how do you conclude $\operatorname{tr}(M)=0$ from $\operatorname{tr}(M^2)=0?$

Comment: @AsafRosemarin $\operatorname{tr}(M)=0$ follows from $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)=\operatorname{tr}(AB)-\operatorname{tr}(BA)$.

Comment: @Benemon the question asks for "a couple solution $(A,B) \in M_3 (\mathbb F_3)$ such that $AB-BA$ is not a scalar matrix".  What does that have to do with $\operatorname{tr}((AB)^2)$ and so on?